# Unignore specific Files in Subdirectory with .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a problem to get .gitignore to do what I want. My folder structure looks like so:

```
assets
├── img
|   ├── thousands
|   ├── of
|   ├── folders
|   ├── KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER
|   |   ├── another
|   |   ├── thousands
|   |   ├── of
|   |   ├── folders
|   |   ├── KEEP_THIS_FILE_1.jpg
|   |   ├── KEEP_THIS_FILE_2.jpg
|   |   ├── KEEP_THIS_FILE_3.jpg
```

I try to keep the three jpgs. I tried

```
/assets/img/*
!/assets/img/KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER/
/assets/img/KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER/*/
!/assets/img/KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER/KEEP_THIS_FILE_*.jpg
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to create .gitignore file in specified folder. In "KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER" in your case. And write this lines:

```
/**
/*.jpg
!not_ignore.jpg
```

At first commit this `.gitignore` file and then try commit your files.
But if your files already has been staged (tracked), try `git rm --cached <filePath>` these files.

Comment: Whereas this is *one* solution, this is not necessary or required for what the OP is asking.

Comment: @denns, at first commit this .gitignore file and then try again

Comment: the commit did not help as well, i git add -f 't the file but no change at all

Comment: @denns Your files already has been staged (tracked), I guess. Try `git rm --cached <filePath>` these files.

Answer (score 15):

When running `man gitignore` from a *nix workstation, and looking at the `PATTERN FORMAT` section, I found the following statement:

> - An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file 
>     excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It
>     is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that
>     file is excluded.** Git doesn't list excluded directories for
>     performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no
>     effect, no matter where they are defined. Put a backslash ("\") in
>     front of the first "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for
>     example, "!important!.txt".

Notice the bolded section. In the case you presented, where you want to unignore files that fall under a sub-directory of the directory you are ignoring, the "un-ignore" `!` operator will not function. Instead, you must be more specific with the ignore pattern.

Try this on for size:

```
/assets/img/*/*
!/assets/img/KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER/KEEP_THIS_FILE*.jpg
```

Comment: Best answer that actually explains the subtlety of ignoring all files in a folder and not the folder itself!

Answer (score 11):

You were close:

```
/assets/img/*
!/assets/img/KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER/

# changed this:
# /assets/img/KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER/*/
# to:
# /assets/img/KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER/*
/assets/img/KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER/*
!/assets/img/KEEP_SOMETHING_IN_THIS_FOLDER/KEEP_THIS_FILE_*.jpg
```

You don't need the trailing slash on the ignore for the child folder (the 3rd line).

Answer (score 7):

you can do like this:

```
# exclude everything except directory foo/bar
/*
!/foo
/foo/*
!/foo/bar
```

and like:

```
# exclude /filepath/includes/a.java
/*
!/filepath
/filepath/*
!/filepath/includes
/filepath/includes/*
!/filepath/includes/a.java
```

by the way If you wanna ignore all **jar** (*.jar), but wanna exclude

> /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

Do this in your **.gitignore**

```
# Package Files #
*.jar
# exclude /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
!/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
```